# Programmatically show message to only specific user

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I made a custom module where I dynamically fetch some usernames from the database. Now I want to send some messages or data to those users' dashboard. I mean that when the selected user is logged in to the website he/she can view the message from their dashboard or profile page. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: did you try "Privatemsg Module". Privatemsg module allows your site's visitors to send private messages to each other.

Comment: Why not use Rules module to trigger the msg or show msg in a block?

Comment: The message is from my own custom module.Can Rules module identify the message generated by the custom module?If yes,please tell me how? @pgrujic

Comment: Take a look at these hooks: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_event_info/7 and http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event/7